# Does my mobile app need a database or should I save everything to files instead?

Tags: database, react-native, mobile, filesystems

I have created a video editor using React Native. I need to choose a way to save all of the user's projects locally. Each project has a video file, thumbnails (images) and its current Redux state.

My first idea is to save everything in files using RNFS. Each Project's folder would have a video file, Thumbnails folder and a state.txt file containing my application's current state (current text size selected, background color, etc...).

Do I need a database like SQLITE or should I save everything in files? I know I'll have to use RNFS for the binary data like videos and images. But what about the state.txt file? is that a good idea? The idea of each user having their own local database just for that sounds strange to me.

Answer (score 0):

You have your Redux state that just represents local state. Have a look at https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist

This allows you to serialize the Redux State and save it using whatever storage you provide, but you can use asyncStorage in the react native apps.

Answer (score 0):

You are right about using RNFS for videos etc. For the metadata in state.txt, in my opinion, it would be better to go with [async-storage](https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage) or other offline storage options (like [Realm](https://realm.io/solutions/offline-first/) )

It will be much more performant to query it instead of reading from a file.